# How to get a value from the InnerHTML through a event Listener if you click on or select it

Tags: javascript, parameters, event-listener

I am Trying to get a value from a Event Listener , I am creating a Game cards it will do comparative among numbers , whatever I select it will take ta value and Run Function it will compare Value bellow there a sneak peak of my Game
[My Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oedZM.png)

this a little of my code i just try to create first a event listener to show my number i want select

```
const speed = document.getElementsByClassName("speed"); //getting the class
```

if I clicked on any speed from any card It will bring me the value

```
speed[3].addEventListener("click", powerSelect); or speed[3].addEventListener("click", battleSpeed(speed[5].innerHTML));
speed[4].addEventListener("click", powerSelect); or speed[4].addEventListener("click", battleSpeed(speed[5].innerHTML));
speed[5].addEventListener("click", powerSelect); or speed[5].addEventListener("click", battleSpeed(speed[5].innerHTML));

function powerSelect(playChoice){
    console.log("Your Choice",playChoice);
}
```

above i tried both events ways did not worked

Comment: Instead of a variety of descriptions of your code, can you update the question to one [mcve] which demonstrates the attempt you've made and the problem you're trying to describe?

Comment: The argument to an event listener is an `Event` object. So `playChoice.target.innerHTML`.

Comment: @Barmar the output i will be this one for ur code  PointerEvent {isTrusted: true, pointerId: 5, width: 1, height: 1, pressure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi Guys i Found the solution in JavaScript Brazil community Facebook
There Two ways to solve

//using this.innerHTML
or using for each

function powerSelect() {
const num = this.innerHTML;`speeds.forEach(speed =>{
speed.addEventListener(“click”, powerSelect) )}
const speeds = document.getElementsByClassName("speed");

//for (let index = 0; index < speeds.length; index++){

//    const speed = speeds[index].innerHTML

```
speeds[0].addEventListener('click', powerSelect);
speeds[1].addEventListener('click', powerSelect);
speeds[2].addEventListener('click', powerSelect);
console.log(num)
```

}

//}
`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code doing these changes:

1. If you want to apply the event listener on all elements with the class `speed` you should use a `for loop`
2. Do not use `or` because does not exist the keyword `or` in JavaScript.

```js
const speeds = document.getElementsByClassName('speed') //getting elements with a class

for (let index = 0; index < speeds.length; index++) {
    const speed = speeds[index]
    speed.addEventListener('click', powerSelect(event))
}

function powerSelect(event) {
    //the event variable is defined by the EventListener on 'click'
    //get the value of the clicked element
    const playChoice = event.target.value
    console.log('Your Choice', playChoice)
}
```

Comment: Hi Mattia I will try , "or" was just a exemple what i have tried .

Comment: Ciao @Mattia today I ran the test its working but it bring me full info about the Dom PointerEvent {isTrusted: true, pointerId: 5, width: 1, height: 1, pressure:

Comment: Where did you declare the `event` variable?